# Is there any utility/plugin for vim editor to add comments/headers?

Tags: c, linux, vim, ubuntu-10.04, vim-plugin

I have searched a number of plugins for adding automatic/manual headers/comments/function details in any C/C++ file when open in vim editor, even tried using **.vimrc** file using **autocommands**. But they are for while opening a new file. Is there any same for already existing files?

Its very tedious for adding information about a code/function in a large code-base.

Comment: comments for file headers and function headers, etc should have been written at the same time as the code.   Note: I find having small files available that contain templates for the file and function headers very handy when generating code as I can just paste their contents where ever needed.

Comment: Yes, comments and headers should be entered during the code writing, but we come under some circumstances that we have to write code 1st for example test apps etc. And if you have a large code base, definitely some other person revise the code base or you yourself and can find things like u have missed something like **headers**, **comments**, **ifdef**, **ifndef** etc. Also, Copying and pasting doesn't give flexibility to customize the templates while entering into the code.

Answer (score 1):

[lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) provides:

- customisable [templates for file headers](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/after/template/c/internals/c-file-header.template)

  - loaded automatically when a new file is created from the file template, before expanding the dedicated [.h](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/after/template/c/internals/c-header.template)/[.cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/blob/master/after/template/c/internals/c-imp.template) file template
  - or on demand as they are 3 ways to trigger a template/snippet expansion (automatically on new files, or on demand with `:MuTemplate c/internals/c-file-header`  here (you can also set an alias to something else) or on snippet expansion). As lh-cpp/mu-template snippets/templates are actually similar to functions/variations points, you can ask to expand only file headers (which are customizable on a per-project basis), or anti-reinclusion guards, and so on.
- `:DOX` command that analyses functions signature to fill the function headers as best as possible
- advanced snippets for various kind of [classes](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/snippets.md#class-patterns) (entity classes, base classes, copiable classes, exception classes, ...) and should eventually fill as much information as possible in the class doxygen from the class semantics -- I just didn't have enough time yet to implement this feature.

Comment: After going through the link of **lh-cpp**, I got to know about **c.vim**. Its light and good tool to customize files and headers. Thanks. @Luc.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches, one using abbreviations and one using snippets.

For example, you could use [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) to add a pre established header.