# How to Insert date in newly created file inside vim?

Tags: datetime, vim

I'm new to vim and I don't know what to look for. That's why I'm asking this question.

I have searched the internet and found it to create a skeleton file for specific filename. I have a file which looks like below:

```
/**
 *  author: 
 *  created: 
**/
```

Is there any way to automatically do something like below when creating a new file.

```
/**
 *  author: mahfuzz
 *  created: 21.04.2020
**/
```

Comment: Here is quite a detailed blogpost: http://brendandawes.com/blog/vim-templates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any utility/plugin for vim editor to add comments/headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769730/is-there-any-utility-plugin-for-vim-editor-to-add-comments-headers)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+new+file+template

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to have some sort of dinamic templates
see [here](https://noahfrederick.com/log/vim-templates-with-ultisnips-and-projectionist)

At `~/.config/nvim/after` I have a file called `ultisnips_custom.vim`

```
"             File: ultisnips_custom.vim - Custom UltiSnips settings
"       Maintainer: Sergio Araújo
" Oririnal Creator: Noah Frederick
"      Last Change: abr 16, 2020 - 14:50
"      Place it at: after/plugin/ultisnips_custom.vim

" We need python or python3 to run ultisnips
if !has("python") && !has("python3")
  finish
endif

" This function is called by the autocommand at the end of the file
function! TestAndLoadSkel() abort
  let filename = expand('%')
  " Abort on non-empty buffer or extant file
  if !(line('$') == 1 && getline('$') == '') || filereadable('%')
    return
  endif

  " Load UltiSnips in case it was deferred via vim-plug
  if !exists('g:did_plugin_ultisnips') && exists(':PlugStatus')
    call plug#load('ultisnips')
    doautocmd FileType
  endif

  " the function feedkys simulates the insert key sequence in order to call
  " the template (skel)
  execute 'call feedkeys("i_skel\<C-r>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()\<CR>")'
endfunction

augroup ultisnips_custom
  autocmd!
  au Bufnewfile *.sh,*.zsh,*.html,*.css,*.py,*.tex,*.md,*.vim :call TestAndLoadSkel()
augroup END

" vim: fdm=marker:sw=2:sts=2:et
```